# Bootstrap 3.0 - issue with the grid-system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a website with bootstrap 3.0, but I have the problem, that the second row (fourth container from total three col-md-4 containers) floats right, but I don't know why.

I already tried to play arrount with the floating, but this was useless.

link: http://www.teuschl.co.at/wir-trauern-um

Comment: What did you try? Please post your html code.

Comment: nothing, because i dont understand this behavior

Answer (score 1):

You should use 4 col-md-3 instead of 4 col-md-4.
grid is divided into 12 blocks. col-md-4*3 covers 12 blocks so the next division goes down.

Comment: it doesn not collapse autmaticly when i have 4 col-md-4? so that the fourth is in the second row? but on the left side?

Comment: So you want the 4th div in your 4 col-md-4's to be on the right side when it's on the 2nd row? Then add col-md-offset-8.